# How to define alphanumeric token in antlr?

Tags: parsing, antlr, grammar

I'd like to have an alphanumeric lexer rule, a token of any combination of letters and digits, here's my grammar

```
grammar Equery;

query:  queryTerm+;

queryTerm:  filter
        |   '(' queryTerm ')'
        ;

filter: kvpair
    |   'NOT' filter
    ;

kvpair: ID '=' VALUE;

ID: [a-zA-Z]+;
VALUE: [a-z0-9]+;
WS: [ \r\n\t]+ -> skip;
```

When I tested the `kvpair` rule with `a=12`, this error occurred:

> mismatched input '12' expecting VALUE

I could work around this, but I'd like to know why *12* is not recognized as a *VALUE*?

Comment: I ran your grammar using antlr4 with "a=12" as the input, and it parses with this tree: `(query (queryTerm (filter (kvpair a = 12))))`. Perhaps you need to recompile, or update your classpath?

Answer (score 1):

Your grammar is correct, as far as I can tell. On my machine using Antlr4, I tested `a = 12` through your kvpair rule, and it parsed fine. As far as I can tell by visual inspection, your code should work on previous versions of Antlr as well. I would try deleting all your Antlr generated files, and rebuilding the grammar to see if that is your issue.